# Installing Craft without installer screens

Tags: installation

Is it possible to install Craft from the command line or without going through the installer screens?

is it as simple as using bootstrap.php and then calling `craft()->install->run($inputs);` with valid inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Would this be something? Craft [CLI Installer](https://github.com/themccallister/craft)

Comment: unfortunately not, that does the same as what i am doing, but it still does not actually complete the installation from this step: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing#step-5-run-the-installer